# Spotify API Web : OAuth without Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth, spotify, webapi

I used the Web API Spotify. I followed the tutorial ( https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/tutorial/ ) to create authentication.
However, it using Node.js and I wonder if we can do without it? (the rest of my code is in JavaScript and does not require Node.js)

Comment: If their API supports CORS, then I don't see why not.

Comment: And what is executing your JavaScript code?

Comment: My JavaScript code create a playlist in spotify and synchonise the tracks from my website to this new playlist spotify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with Spotify's Web API using only frontend code.

You might want to have a look at the [JavaScript wrapper](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js) as it offers language bindings for all API endpoints so it should save you  a lot of time. If you're working without a backend, the only way to retrieve access tokens is through the Implicit Grant flow, see [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow) or [demo application](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples) for more detailed information.