# Given the new Spotify web api authentication credentials, is it possible to run the api without a server?

Tags: node.js, api, npm, browserify, spotify

I'm trying to run the spotify web api using node-spotify-api npm package. In order to require the package I have to use something called browserify, which allows me to specifically use the "require()" function in the browser. I'm strictly trying to run the api on the client side. When I do, this is the error I get -

```
    // I have my client ID and client secret ID delcared in variables
    // Code below is suppose to execute the search function once the user enters a track

    var query = $("#query").val().trim();
     console.log(query)
    spotify.search({ type: 'track', query: query }, function(err, data) 
      {
      if (err) {
        return console.log('Error occurred: ' + err);
      }

    console.log(data); 

    });



// Once executed, I get the error below

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque 
response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to 
fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
bundle.js:120 Error occurred: RequestError: TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I looked up the error and everything I'm looking at redirects me in the direction of running the api on the server side which I do not want to do if possible. Any thoughts on how to strictly run this client-side?

Comment: Please show us the actual Spotify request you're trying to make.  The specific error you point to is a cross-origin access error and means that either the site you're trying to access does not allow cross origin access or you aren't making the request in a proper way to do a cross origin request.  We need to know more about the API request you're trying to make to have any idea which of those it is.

Comment: I'm wondering if this [Spotify API Web : OAuth without Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073752/spotify-api-web-oauth-without-node-js?rq=1) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Just updated my question with the spotify call. As for the OAuth link, I looked at that same repo and to my understanding, that example is operable from server side. If possible, I want to run this as a front end app and deploy it as a front end app. Essentially, I wondering if you can use node.js for front end apps.

Comment: Well, you can't use node.js for front-end apps that run in the browser as node.js does not run in a browser.  You have to write browser-based Javascript to run in a browser.  For example, there's no `http` module in the browser.  Instead, you'd have to make Ajax calls with `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()`.  There are spotify wrappers for use in the browser.  I think that's probably what you want.

Comment: I found something called browserify - http://browserify.org/
Allowed me to run node.js in the browser; specifically allowing me to use require(" ")
I still ran into this error which Is associated with spotify. The error is console.log inside the spotify function.
I initially used an ajax call to run spotify web api which worked flawless and that was a front end app. Ever since spotify changed access to the api, I now have problems running it as a front end app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing the auth flow called [Client Credentials](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow), and **no, this is not possible** because Spotify refuses to allow CORS on their auth token endpoint. [See this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/639).

You will need to use the [Implicit Grant flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow) to utilize the API entirely within the browser.

Comment: FWIW, I think it's stupid that Spotify refuses to enable CORS on the auth token endpoint and also doesn't have a public API (public meaning one that doesn't require authentication). They are forcing people, who want to make public use of the API, to incur server costs.